# How can I allow Arabic usernames in WordPress

Tags: username, characters

I want to let users put there username in Arabic when they register a new account, I tried a lot of methods put problem still unsolved

Answer (score 1):

You can try [WordPress Special Characters in Usernames](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-special-characters-in-usernames/) plugin.
This plugin enables usernames containing special characters (russian, cyrillic, **arabic**) on your WordPress blog.

Comment: not work well, i want coding not plugin

Comment: It's only a few hundred lines, and most of that is config. And it's already written and testsed. I'm sure you could skim it to understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

By default WordPress limits non-Latin characters on usernames for security reasons but To allow users to use non-Latin letters in the username field, you can use the following code:

```
add_filter('sanitize_user', 'non_strict_login', 10, 3);
function non_strict_login( $username, $raw_username, $strict ) {

    if( !$strict )
        return $username;

    return sanitize_user( stripslashes( $raw_username ), false );
}
```

Add the above code to the 'functions.php' file in your WordPress theme's directory.